# Can typescript get/infer the type of a react context based on the provided value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript

Can typescript get/infer the type of a react context based on the provided value.Or do I have to create the interface/type manually.

Please check the scenario below.

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext(null)

const MyProvider = ({children})=>{

  const myName = 'John Doe'
  
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{myName}} >
    {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )

}

.
.

const ctx = useContext(MyContext)

// And then the type of ctx would be {myName : string}. Is this possible with typescript?
```

Answer (score 1):

The type is determined when you create the context. Ie, this line:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(null)
```

Typescript can do inference from this, but if you're passing in null for the default value, it will infer the type of the value to be null. So if you need the value to be able to change to a non-null value later, you'll need to be more explicit:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext<{ myName: string } | null>(null)
```

With a different default value, the inference may be better:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext({ myName: 'bob' });
```